# MatLab Simulink for Mac - How to connect multiple blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using MatLab and Simulink on Mac OS X.

I need to connect one block to multiple blocks. It seems that in Windows you can just click on the existing line, hold on control button, and click on the destination block (as http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/connecting-blocks.html says). But in Mac, it doesn't do anything.

All the tutorials I found are for Windows. And Simulink interface looks very different (looks like X11 or Java graphical user interface).

In Simulink on Mac, how do you draw a second connection line to another block?

It's very frustrating that this supposed-to-be simple operation takes so long to figure out.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you try starting at the input of the second block and tracing back to the line that you want to connect? That is how I usually do it on Windows, although I cannot verify that it works on Mac.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Engineero. Yes, I tried it and it worked. How simple it was! I had tried all the key combinations like Shift, etc. and never tried connecting backward, thinking it can reverse input and output...

Comment: Now, I cannot connect from the output of the second block to the existing block with its input already connected to yet another existing block. It adds red dotted line instead. What is this red dot line and how can I connect the black solid line instead? Thank you in advance. By the way, I'm simply trying to follow the tutorial, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfXBw51xKr0

Comment: If you are trying to connect two different inputs to a single block with only one input terminal, you might have to add some sort of switching block with two inputs and one output before-hand. If you just wire the outputs of two blocks together and plug them in to the input of a third block, it may cause problems. You could also bundle or "mux" the wires together to form an input array. Is there any chance you could post a picture with the problem you are seeing?

Comment: Hi, Engineero. Thank you for your reply. I have added the picture.

Comment: Are you trying to display all three signals (your saturated continuous signal, and the output of both of your ZOH blocks) on the scope? If so, I suggest using the "mux" block to combine these three wires into one and passing that one to the scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Engineero. I have been following the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfXBw51xKr0 and it's not using mux block. But I will try it.

Comment: Yes, the scope only takes one input, which is why it's not letting you add more, but that input can be a vector. See [`mux`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/mux.html) and [`demux`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/demux.html).